# 使用していない JavaScript の削除について

Tags: javascript

PageSpeed Insights で計測したところ、

> 使用していない JavaScript を削除して、データ通信量を減らしてください

とのことで、以下のようなコードが10個くらいあります。

**URL**

```
/js/vendor.js?version=96be8d4…&env=production(cdn.blog.st-hatena.com)
250.9 KiB
171.8 KiB
```

**質問①**
以上のような表示がありますが、そもそも自分のサイトのどの部分かがわかりません。
どうやって確認するのでしょうか？

**質問②**
上のコードをクリックするとさらに、長いコードが表示されますが、それを圧縮してサイト記事内（html)に戻せばよいのですか？

どうそ、よろしくお願い致します。
サイトはこちらです。
https://www.kaminoonayami.jp/

Answer (score 3):

前提として
PageSpeed Insights
の診断結果をすべての対応ができるとは限りません。

サイト及びサーバの運営管理者であれば問題なく対応できますが、
たとえばはてなブログなどブログサービス利用していて、サーバやサイトの管理者はサービス提供者であり、自分がそのサービスの１利用者でしかない場合はできることは限られてきます。

今回の場合はJavascriptの圧縮や削除を考えているようですが、おそらく自分で設置したものでない限りはサービス提供者が設置したものになるので、そのサービス提供者に問い合わせするのが筋でしょう。

その上で回答させていただきます。

> 質問① 以上のような表示がありますが、そもそも自分のサイトのどの部分かがわかりません。 どうやって確認するのでしょうか？

自分で設置したものであれば、必ずサイトに自分が設置した記述があるのでソースコードを追いかけて探すしかないです。

自分が設置したものでないとするとなかなか削除するのは難しいですが、一般的にサービスとして提供されているものかもしくは外部連携（twitterやfacebookなど）で追加されているのになるはずです。

どのjavascriptかわからないのであればChormeで対象の画面を開いてF12（開発者ツール）を押すことで、どのJavascriptが読み込まれているか確認できます。

該当のスクリプトははてな系の何かしらのツールっぽいのではてなに問い合わせしてみてはどうでしょうか？
（cdn.blog.st-hatena.comというドメインで判断しました）
またすでに圧縮はそれなりにされていそうなので削除した対応できなさそうですが、削除すると何かしらの機能が動かなくなる可能性もあります。そこもよく問い合わせてみてはいかがでしょうか？

> 質問② 上のコードをクリックするとさらに、長いコードが表示されますが、それを圧縮してサイト記事内（html)に戻せばよいのですか？

ここでいう圧縮はminifyだと仮定してお話します。
上のソースコードはすでに圧縮されているようですが、もし更に文字を圧縮してサイト内記事に戻しても、それ自体が外部読み込みになっているので２重で読み込まれてしまい、不具合が起きる可能性があります。
自分で置いたJavascriptでなければ基本的にそのJavascriptの提供者に問い合わせしましょう。

もちろん自分で置いたJavascriptであれば圧縮することでコンテンツ量の読み込みが減ることになるでしょう。

Comment: 詳しく説明いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: さっそく、管理側へ問合せをしています。わかりやすくご教授いただき、感謝いたします。